# CSS: Issue with transparency of sidebar div with footer background-color

Tags: html, css

I have issue with the transparency which I have on my sidebar with the footer background-color. You can see it underneath it like so:

I tried setting z-index but it didn't work and I can't just set some color on the sidebar. It needs to be a Gradient...

[image]

How should I deal with this issue ?

```
header
{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%, rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 41%, rgba(0,0,0,0.11) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(19%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(41%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.11)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 41%,rgba(0,0,0,0.11) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 41%,rgba(0,0,0,0.11) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 41%,rgba(0,0,0,0.11) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 41%,rgba(0,0,0,0.11) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#1c000000',GradientType=1 );
}
#container
{
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
}

#content
{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
footer
{
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  background-color:#333333;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 300px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     ...
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You state that you have an issue but you don't clearly state what the _problem_ is.

Comment: When you say "I tried setting z-index but it didn't work", if you mean you tried setting a z-index on your footer, keep in mind that z-index only affects 'positioned' elements (ie, elements with the attribute `position:relative`, `position:fixed`, or `position:absolute`)

Comment: Firstly, the other div is transparent so even with a z-index you would see the foot through it either way. Have you tried setting a specific height for the footer or the other div?